# Inspect or Visualize in memory database created using sqlite jdbc during debug

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, sqlitejdbc

I am creating a temporary sqlite jdbc database structure in memory.
Somehitng like this,

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

However, it would be really nice to be able to see/visualize this database while debugging.
I have created a complete set of database and can retrieve this data using `ResultSet and Statement.executeQuery("Query");`

Any ideas, how can it be achieved in Netbeans debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-memory databases cannot be accessed from another connection.

For debugging, create a database in a file.